# Java Freezes when input is one million

Tags: java

My program freezes when I enter one million as a number for input. How do I fix this?

I tried separating second for loop as a second function, it didn't work.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Array {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String line = System.console().readLine("How many digits of Pi do you want? ");
  int n = Integer.parseInt(line);

  int columns = (int)(10.0*n/3.0);

  int[][] makedigitsofpi = new int[columns][2];
  makedigitsofpi[0][0] = 30;
  makedigitsofpi[0][1] = 10;
  for(int i = 1; i < columns; i++) {
           makedigitsofpi[i][0] = i;
           makedigitsofpi[i][1] = i*2+1;
  }
  int[] make2s = new int[columns];
  for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            make2s[i] = 2;
  }
  int[] timesby10 = new int[columns];
  int[] thirdrow = new int[columns];
  int[] fourrow = new int[columns];
  int[] fifthrow = new int[columns];
  for(int four_rows = 0; four_rows < n; four_rows++) {
         for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
               timesby10[i] = make2s[i]*10;
         }
         for(int column = (columns - 1); column >= 0; column--) {
                if(columns == (column + 1)) { //last column
            thirdrow[column] = 0; // add last
            }
            else { // Third Row
                    int[] cell0 = makedigitsofpi[(column+1)];
                    int cellfour = fourrow[(column+1)];
                    int cellfive = fifthrow[(column+1)];
            int d = cellfour - cellfive;
                thirdrow[column] = (d*cell0[0])/cell0[1];
            }
         }
     }
  }
}
```

I need my program to be able to handle large numbers. This program is only the start of my project. The project is to create a program that generates Pi to a unlimited amount of digits.

Comment: Define "freezes" - how long does it take? How long does it take for other inputs?

Comment: The program keeps blinking the cursor in the console with the processor not processing the program. For other inputs it takes less than a second. The program also freezes for a hundred thousand input.

Comment: What about 50.000 - does that still "work"? What I'm trying to get at, how does runtime increase (in O notation)? How does that deviate from your expactations?

Comment: 50,000 doesn't work but 10,000 does.

Comment: I just ran your code and after i inputted the first value,the program exited

Comment: I want the program to exit. When the input is a million or a hundred thousand the program doesn't exit. When the program exits that means the program has finished execution which means the program worked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I fix this?

Do the work in background thread.

Your code is working, the processor is used, doing math.

The "freeze" it is because it is not handling your inputs and is not finished his job.

To finish earlier the job, give smaller number of course.

To handle your imputs you need to do those for loops in a separated `Thread` 
The code will not ececute faster, but you will not have the "freeze" feeling. If you would have a button to start in this case the button would be pressed and stay pressed, no other input.

In multi threaded context the button would release and you could switch from "start" state to "stop" state and if you press the button again, you set a Boolean variable value toggle: ex `shouldCalculate = false;` In your for loop if check that value, if is false, than exit from the thread, that's all.

Please take a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) to work with threads.